# Metodologia BEM e sub-blocos

Tags: css, bem

Estou tendo duvidas sobre melhores praticas utilizando a metodologia [BEM](http://getbem.com/), veja abaixo um exemplo (exemplo com Jade):

```
nav(class='c-ngroup')
  div(class='wrap')
    div(class='row')
      div(class='col-md--2')
        h4(class='c-ngroup__title') Promote
        ul(class='c-ngroup__list')
          li(class='c-ngroup__list__item')
            a(href='#', class='c-ngroup__list__link') Event
          li(class='c-ngroup__list__item')
            a(href='#', class='c-ngroup__list__link') Place
          li(class='c-ngroup__list__item')
            a(href='#', class='c-ngroup__list__link') Promotion
```

Perceba que estou aninhando dois níveis de elementos `c-ngroup__list__item`, isso seria uma pratica ruim? Existe alguma forma melhor de fazer isso?

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiramente o processo da metodologia BEM tem como premissa: blocos é um conjunto de elementos, entretanto elementos podem vir a ver blocos, e claro,  ambos podem possuir modificações.

Veja sua estrutura:

```
nav.c-ngroup

  //-div e bloco class modificador 
modificador

  div.wrap

    //- bloco

    .row

      //- col bloco md-2 modificador

      .col-md-2

        //- elemento

        h4.c-ngroup__title Promote

        //- bloco 

        ul.c-ngroup__list

          // elemento/ bloco

          li.c-ngroup__list__item

            //- elemento semântico 

            a(href='#') Event
         ...
```

CSS/less

```
.c-ngroup__list{
   &__title{
   }
   &__item{
     a{

     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Tentei contribuir através do celular mas pelo visto ele ficou bem estranho.. obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Sim, aninhar dois níveis de elementos é uma prática ruim no BEM. O correto, [segundo a metodologia](https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#why-does-bem-not-recommend-using-elements-within-elements-block__elem1__elem2), é ignorar os níveis intermediários ao nomear as classes dos elementos.

A classe `c-ngroup__list__item` ficaria `c-ngroup__item` e a classe `c-ngroup__list__link` ficaria `c-ngroup__link`.